# In C#, Is it slower to reference an array variable?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, performance, optimization

I've got an array of integers, and I'm looping through them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
  // do a lot of stuff here using data[i]
}
```

If I do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
  int value = data[i];
  // do a lot of stuff with value instead of data[i]
}
```

Is there any performance gain/loss?

From my understanding, C/C++ array elements are accessed directly, i.e. an n-element array of integers has a contiguous memory block of length n * sizeof(int), and the program access element i by doing something like *data[i] = *data[0] + (i * sizeof(int)). (Please excuse my abuse of notation, but you get what I mean.)

So this means C/C++ should have no performance gain/loss for referencing array variables.

What about C#?
C# has a bunch of extra overhead like data.Length, data.IsSynchronized, data.GetLowerBound(), data.GetEnumerator().

Clearly, a C# array is not the same as a C/C++ array.

So what's the verdict? Should I store int value = data[i] and work with value, or is there no performance impact?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: Very negligible, I would assume, if any.

Comment: On something very similar, my team has noticed a significant savings by loading the indexed value into a local variable and referencing it as opposed to referencing the indexed value all the time.

Comment: @Jeremy Holovacs Of course. Local variables are stored on stack! If it propagates to CPU level 3/2/1 cache it will be many times faster than accessing array on heap.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes**, there is a performance loss due to the bounds check for every access to the array.

**No**, you most likely don't need to worry about it.

Yes, you can should store the value and work with the value. No, this isn't because of the performance issue, but rather because it makes the code more readable (IMHO).

---

By the way, the JIT compiler *might* optimize out redundant checks, so it doesn't mean you'll actually get a check on every call. Either way, it's probably not worth your time to worry about it; just use it, and if it turns out to be a bottleneck you can always go back and use `unsafe` blocks.

Comment: Because really every good optimizer (well at least for languages like Java or C#, that's no universal truth) will do common subexpression elimination which will eliminate that performance loss. And in the specified code bounds checking will be used anyhow.

Comment: I believe the JIT'ter optimizes bounds checking away for common loops like that, that simply can't throw out of range exceptions.

Answer (score 24):

You can have the cake and eat it too.  There are many cases where the jitter optimizer can easily determine that an array indexing access is safe and doesn't need to be checked.  Any for-loop like you got in your question is one such case, the jitter knows the range of the index variable.  And knows that checking it again is pointless.

The only way you can see that is from the generated machine code.  I'll give an annotated example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
        for (int ix = 0; ix < array.Length; ++ix) {
            int value = array[ix];
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }

Starting at the for loop, ebx has the pointer to the array:

            for (int ix = 0; ix < array.Length; ++ix) {
00000037  xor         esi,esi                       ; ix = 0
00000039  cmp         dword ptr [ebx+4],0           ; array.Length < 0 ?
0000003d  jle         0000005A                      ; skip everything
                int value = array[ix];
0000003f  mov         edi,dword ptr [ebx+esi*4+8]   ; NO BOUNDS CHECK !!!
                Console.WriteLine(value);
00000043  call        6DD5BE38                      ; Console.Out
00000048  mov         ecx,eax                       ; arg = Out
0000004a  mov         edx,edi                       ; arg = value
0000004c  mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx]           ; call WriteLine()
0000004e  call        dword ptr [eax+000000BCh] 
            for (int ix = 0; ix < array.Length; ++ix) {
00000054  inc         esi                           ; ++ix
00000055  cmp         dword ptr [ebx+4],esi         ; array.Length > ix ?
00000058  jg          0000003F                      ; loop
```

The array indexing happens at address 00003f, ebx has the array pointer, esi is the index, 8 is the offset of the array elements in the object.  Note how the esi value is not checked again against the array bounds.  This runs just as fast as the code generated by a C compiler.

Comment: Just because it doesn't check here doesn't mean it normally doesn't. If you'd read my answer carefully, you'd have noticed my comment on the JIT optimization, which is exactly what you're mentioning here. But note that this does *not* work if you don't first check against `array.Length`; it only works because the JIT can prove you'll never get an out-of-bounds error (which it can't always do).

Comment: I thought it important to address the OP's scenario.  He's right to bring it up, loops are important.  That's where the effects of inefficient code quickly multiply.  The core answer is that it **does** work, not 'only because' or 'might optimize'.

Comment: @Hans: Not always -- not, for example, if the variable is captured in a lambda. Simple loops don't mean that this optimization will always happen.

Comment: Hmya, the jitter was optimized to produce good results on common code fragments.  It can certainly be defeated.  I don't know good examples of that off-hand, I stopped looking when I concluded "wow, that's pretty damn good, I'll use that now".

Comment: @Hans: Lambdas *are* pretty common nowadays (in fact, *too* common IMHO)... and my answer certainly isn't "wrong". :\

Comment: @Hans: I kinda was, yeah. +1 now for actually taking the time to disassemble. :)

Comment: @Hans, you say that the jitter optimiser knows the range of the indeces and hence doesn't need to do a bounds check. What if I put a `i = 1000000;` line in my for loop? Does the optimiser analyse the code inside the loop and determine that I'm doing something fishy with the index and do a bounds check?

Comment: In that case you will *really* appreciate that C# does array bound checking.  The jitter isn't going to stop you from doing something wrong, it only helps when you do it right.

Comment: @Ozzah: Well if the JIT works similar to Java/Hotspot, it may optimize the code based on the assumption that you don't set i yourself in the loop. As soon as you do that, the assumption is proven wrong and it'll fall back into interpreted mode where you get the boundary checks.

Comment: will JIT also optimize when array contains structs? I assume no because it causes copying a value type, but maybe I'm wrong? can jitter take reference to indexed item in assembly level?

Comment: copying struct causes all  fields to be copied, but you may want to access a few of fields, so in this case storing `data[i]` into local field is worse (one thinks its optimizing but is actually pessimizing)

Comment: The array element type does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

You have written it both ways. Run it both ways, measure it. Then you'll know.

But I think you would prefer working with the copy rather than always working with the array element directly, simply because it's *easier to write the code that way*, particularly if you have lots of operations involving that particular value.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can only perform common subexpression optimization here if it can prove that the array isn't accessed by other threads or any methods (including delegates) called inside the loop, it might be better to create the local copy yourself.

But readability should be your main concern, unless this loop executes a huge number of times.

All of this is also true in C and C++ -- indexing into an array will be slower than accessing a local variable.

As a side note, your suggested optimization is no good: `value` is a keyword, choose a different variable name.

Comment: Thanks, yeah my example was just for illustration purposes - I would normally use something shorter like 'val' or 'num' for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure, but it probably wouldn't hurt to store the value if you are going to use it multiple times. You could also use a foreach statement :)

Comment: From what I remember, foreach is slower than for, and has the limitation that you can't modify the size of the array you're working on. For example foreach(object o in objectList){if(condition(o))objectList.Remove(o);} will throw an exception.