# Why get data from references slower then calculate in c#?

Tags: c#, performance

I test 2 type to get my data **behind loop of 65,000,000**. The different is 0.5-0.6 seconds.

Test 1:

```
 ushort e = myFunction(a, b, c);
 ushort d = (ushort)(e + (f << 13));

private static ushort myFunction(ushort a, int b, int c) {
if (a < (ushort)b)
       return 0;

if (a > (ushort)c)
      return (ushort)(c - b);

return (ushort)(a - b);
```

Test 2:

```
ushort d = arr2Dimension[i, j].data;
```

`data` is public data member of class type of `arr2Dimension`.

I checked the time for each one of the test (separately) 3 times, the first test was always faster around 0.5-0.6 seconds.

Why that? (why to get data by reference slower?)

Comment: could the data member be a property that involves additional computation?

Comment: No, data contain the value d from the first test by precalculate, and I check the time only on those rows (include the loop)

Comment: perhaps this is relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575155/in-c-is-it-slower-to-reference-an-array-variable

Comment: When i changed the arr to one dimension the performance +- equal, @fusi thank you.

Comment: Neither one of those actions is going to be taking anywhere even remotely close to half a second.  Both of those actions are going to be fractions of a millisecond.  If you're recording anything else then your benchmarking code is seriously broken.  Of course, these two actions being of comparable times isn't surprising at all; both ought to be able to be resolved extremely quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to give you an accurate answer when you don't post code that we can actually try to run ourselves.  But yes, there is a pattern to code like this, you basically discovered that accessing memory is one of the slowest things that a processor can do.

It is problem related to *distance*, the further an electronic circuit is physically removed, the slower the signal must be to ensure that it doesn't get corrupted.  It is the basic principle of "there is no free lunch" in electronic engineering.  And why new processors that use smaller feature sizes in silicon are automatically faster.

Your myFunction() method uses processor resources that are very close together.  The a, b and c variables and the method return value are stored in *registers*, a very small storage location that is *very* close to the processor's execution engine.  As close as it can be.  Expectation is that this code runs at full bore, executing several instructions concurrently for each clock cycle.  It *might* be bogged down a bit by the if() statements, they are only fast if the processor has good branch prediction data available.  Depends on how consistently the branch was taken in previous executions of the method.  Or in other words, how random the a, b and c values are.

The array however requires accessing circuits that are *not* close to the processor.  The array element might be present in the L1 cache, that takes 3 cycles.  Can be a single cycle if the prefetcher guessed at it correctly.  When the array is large then speed starts to tank when the processor can only find it in the L2 or L3 cache.  It will be dreadful when it has to be retrieved from RAM, the processor will be stalled for a fat 150 cycles waiting for the RAM to supply the data.  Distance acting up, you can pop the case and *see* the wires that connect the RAM to the processor.