# Difference in performance to assign array to local variable instead of inside a loop

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

I tend to do this:

```
var x = arr[i];

for (int j = 0; j < J; j++)
{
    // use x instead of arr[i]
}
```

Another way would be without assigning to a local variable, and using the array access directly:

```
for (int j = 0; j < J; j++)
{
    // use arr[i] each time
}
```

Is the difference negligible or not? For a small number of iterations I shouldn't worry about the difference, but what about a great number of iterations, like 100 million?

Comment: [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In C#, Is it slower to reference an array variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575155/in-c-is-it-slower-to-reference-an-array-variable)